# PivotTable advanced filtering

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, filtering, pivot-table

I need help with filtering data from a PivotTable in Excel. I have to make a PivotChart with filtering TOP 10 data and with one special value. If this special value isn't in TOP10 I still need this value in the PivotChart. When I filter data with TOP10 condition and add another condition it does not work.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: This can be achieved either by using formulas or with VBA, would you post the PivotTable in question and a small but significant section of your data, in order to provide a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Least impractical seems to be to go to the PT filter and select (individually) the Top 10 plus the special case.